# how to put formulas and tikz plots into bookdown table cells?

Tags: bookdown

I know how to typeset formulas and tikz plots in bookdown:

````
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
1/2 & \mbox{if $-1 \leq x \leq 1$} \\
0 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

```{tikz kuniform, echo=FALSE, cache=TRUE}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)}]
\draw[->] (-1.7,0) -- (1.9,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-.2) -- (0,1.4) node[right]{$K(x)$};
\draw (-1,0.1) -- (-1,-0.1) node[below] {$-1$};
\draw (1,0.1) -- (1,-0.1) node[below] {$1$};
\draw[thick] (-1.6,0) -- (-1,0);
\draw[thick] (-1,.5) -- (1,.5);
\draw[thick] (1,0) -- (1.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

The output works nicely both for HTML (`bookdown::gitbook`) and PDF (`bookdown::pdf_book`) output.  I can also do tables:

```
Name     | Plot      | $K(x) = \cdots$
-------- | --------- | ---------------
Uniform  | Plot here | Formula here
Another  | ...       | ...
```

But how can I get the plot to show in the table cell where it says "Plot here", and the formula in the table cell marked "Formula here"?